# How can I order my results asc with Java?

Tags: java, sorting

I want to order my users with their ages in ascending order like. (like asc does in php mysql)

I get all data from mysql table like that;

```
id  name  age  country
1   alex  21    Brazil
2   maria 34    England
3   ...   56    ...
```

My question is:
I use Java table sorter for ordering data, my users can easyly be ordered to younger user or older.
If you clicked id button ids can asc or desc it works with no problem, but if you clicked age button, table sorter would order ages like that **5**78 < **8**6 < **9**.
It seems just considering the first character. I tried to change data string to integer but it failed.

Comment: you should post java code too

Comment: A code snippet would help.

Comment: why don't you bring the sorted data via mysql directyl by the query?

Comment: Have you tried any code?!

Comment: The `age` column has to be a numeric type (eg. `INT`) to sort numerically. More than that I cannot say without seeing some code.

Comment: You tried to change the data type from string to integer? It failed? Try harder. That's the solution.

Comment: If the Java table sorter does not have the concept of numbers, abandon it!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `age` from a `String` into an `int` is the right approach. The ordering you gave clearly is based on a `char` comparison. The easiest way to solve this would be by selecting `age` as an `int` in the first place.

```
Convert(age, unsigned integer)
```

Should do that in MySQL.

In Java, you could use:

```
Integer.parseInt(age);
```

Comment: Although not part of the question, having a field called age is a very bad idea. Much better is to have a Date field for dateOfBirth and calculate age on demand.